# drupal skips "install site" step

Tags: .htaccess, drupal

I am on Windows 10 and I trying to install Drupal 8 (v8.2.3). I am using MAMP for my localhost.
Installation step fails after I choose my database so in other words it fails to reach **Install site** step . It doesnt show in the screenshot but I do select the right database.
[image: drupal installation]

After I click on **Save and continue** I get this 
[image: drupal error]

When I reload the page I get this
[image: drupal error]

And when I press on View your existing site I get the not found error
[image] . I tried to add this .htaccess code http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/plain/.htaccess?id=HEAD
but it only skips the requirements step in installation. I also have OPcache enabled on MAMP but it doesnt really affect anything.

Answer (score 0):

An HTTP 500 error is an internal server error. What's most likely is that PHP is encountering a fatal error, which causes the process to fail.

You'll need to check your MAMP logs to find out exactly what's going wrong.

Open terminal, and run the following:

```
tail /Applications/MAMP/logs/php_error.log    
tail /Applications/MAMP/logs/apache_error_log
```

One of these filesshould have the error you're running into. If you don't see any error messages, enable PHP error logging is enabled by adding the following to your .conf file:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_flag display_errors on
</IfModule>
```